# images from database not getting loaded in Jssor Slider

Tags: javascript, image, slider, loading, jssor

Hi I am working on integrating JSSOR slider with my database images.

I added code in my index.html.

```
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 600px; height: 327px; background: #fff; overflow: hidden; ">

    <!-- Slides Container -->
  <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left:50px; right:20px; top: 50px; width: 475px; height: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;">

       <div>
            <img src="test/01.jpg" />
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

then in my js file

```
/*Gallery Item Start*/

  $('#galleryItem').on('pageshow', function ()
   {
                       var verticaltext = "";

                       var allItems = Tables.images.all();

                       var rating = [];
                       allItems.list(null, function (results)
                                     {
                                     results.forEach(function (r)
                                         {

                                     // alert(JSON.stringify(r));
                                         rating.push([r.capturedDate, r.name, r.ratingTreatment, r.ratingSkinCleansing, r.ratingPlucking, r.ratingView, r.ratingLastVal, r.capturedDate]);

                                         });

                                     $.each(rating, function (key, value) {
                                            console.log("record is " + value[1]);
                                            verticaltext = verticaltext + "<div><img  src=" + value[1] +"></div>"
                                            });

//                                     verticaltext = verticaltext + "</div>";
                                     console.log("FULL HTML IS " +verticaltext);
                                     sliderDataReady(verticaltext);
                                     });

    });


/*created a function which should be called with the ready html to bind to 
JSSOR SLider*/

 function sliderDataReady(slideData)
  {
  console.log("slider1_container HTML : " +$('#slider1_container').html());

  console.log(" slides HTML : " +$('#slides').html());


  $('#slides').append(slideData);

  console.log(" slides HTML : " +$('slides').html());

  /* Gallery items carousel slider - start */
  var options = {
  $StartIndex: 0,                 //[Optional] Index of slide to display when initialize, default value is 0

  $LazyLoading: 3,
  $AutoPlay: false,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
  $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
  $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
  $PauseOnHover: 3,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1
  $Loop: 0,                                      // Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
  $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                        //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
  $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
  $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
  //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
  //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
  $SlideSpacing: 5,                                     //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
  $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
  $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
  $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
  $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
  $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

  $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
  $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
  $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
  $ActionMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
  $AutoCenter: 3,                             //[Optional] Auto center thumbnail items in the thumbnail navigator container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 3
  $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange thumbnails, default value is 1
  $SpacingX: 1,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
  $SpacingY: 0,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
  $DisplayPieces: 5,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
  $ParkingPosition: 0,                            //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail
  $Orientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
  $DisableDrag: true                              //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
  }
  };

//  var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

  var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(options)

  //responsive code begin
  //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
  function ScaleSlider() {
  var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
  if (parentWidth) {
  var sliderWidth = parentWidth;

  //keep the slider width no more than 600
  sliderWidth = Math.min(sliderWidth, 600);

  jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(sliderWidth);
  }
  else
  window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
  }
  ScaleSlider();

  $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
  $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
  $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
  //responsive code end


  /* JSSOR EVENTS*/
  jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_CLICK, SlideShowSlideIndex);
  jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_DRAG_START, SlideShowStartDragSlide);
  jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_DRAG_END, SlideShowEndDragSlide);
  jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_SLIDESHOW_END, SlideShowEnded);
  jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_POSITION_CHANGE, SlidePositionChanged);
  jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, SlideStoppedSliding);
  }
```

I tried to get the html and then called a method to load my JSSOR slider.

Please correct me where i am wrong

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code $('#slides').append(slideData), please add id attribute to 'slides' container.

```
<div id="slides" u="slides"
```

Comment: Thanks @Jssor, How do i refresh my slider everytime on page show ? if i use    $('#slider1_container').remove(); then it removes my slider but after that if i use jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);  It does not refresh or recreates my slider

Comment: When you get the 'slider1_removed', you need to manually recreate 'slider1_container' and insert it into dom. And then you can reinitialize jssor slider with statement jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);